# Unnest a ts class

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, exponential, unnest

My data has multiple customers data with different start and end dates along with their sales data.So I did simple exponential smoothing.
I applied the following code to apply `ses`

```
library(zoo)
library(forecast)

z <- read.zoo(data_set,FUN = function(x) as.Date(x) + seq_along(x) / 10^10 , index = "Date", split = "customer_id")
L <- lapply(as.list(z), function(x) ts(na.omit(x),frequency = 52))
HW <- lapply(L, ses)
```

Now my output class is `list` with uneven lengths.Can someone help me how to unnest or unlist the output in to a data frame and get the fitted values,actuals,residuals along with their dates,sales and customer_id.
Note : the reson I post my input data rather than data of `HW` is,the `HW` data is too large.
Can someone help me in R.

Comment: Please be clear, are you using `forecast::ses`?

Comment: Yes@r2evans and edited my question.Thanks!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I tried your method but it showed me like columns names like `Point Forecast` , `Lo 80`, `Hi 80` basically it showed me the intervals other than the fitted values and actual values which we can see in dput(HW) or view of HW.

Comment: In order to unlist your output, you need to convert each element from class `forecast` to `data.frame`, and then you can bind the list elements together using `bind_rows` from package `dplyr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly took all the unique customer_id into a variable called 'k'

```
 k <- unique(data_set$customer_id)
```

Created a empty data frame

```
   b <- data.frame()
```

extracted all the fitted values using a for loop and stored in 'a'.Using the rbind function attached all the fitted values to data frame 'b'

```
for(key in k){    
  print(a <- as.data.frame((as.numeric(HW_ses[[key]]$model$fitted))))
  b <- rbind(b,a)     
    }
```

Finally using column bind function attached the input data set with data frame 'b'

```
data_set_final <- cbind(data_set,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `tidyverse` package to handle this problem.

```
map(HW, ~ .x %>% 
      as.data.frame %>%             # convert each element of the list to data.frame
      rownames_to_column) %>%       # add row names as columns within each element
  bind_rows(.id = "customer_id")    # bind all elements and add customer ID
```

I am not sure how to relate dates and actual sales to your output (`HW`). If you explain it I might provide solution to that part of the problem too.

Comment: Still no luck,the output is showing only Lo and Hi values.I just want the actual values(from input),dates(from input) alsong with their customer_id and their exponential values in a data frame.

Comment: @riyan, can you show what the final table should look like. For instance, for customer "I-H0188" how do you want to combine HW and input data.